# Pull a saved query into Metabase

Tags: database, google-bigquery, metabase

I created a saved query in Bigquery and I would like to pull that saved query into metabase. Does anyone know if this is possible? I am not able to export it to a JSON file.

[Saved Query in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykKUP.png)

These are my only options:
[Export Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flxtg.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshots provided, that isn't a "Saved query". What you are talking about is a VIEW. Unfortunately, you can't export views. This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views-intro#view_limitations).

> You cannot run a BigQuery job that exports data from a view.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/saving-sharing-queries) is documentation for "Saved queries" which is different than views.

> This page describes how to save and share queries. Queries that are saved or shared contain only the query itself, which means that:

> - A shared query provides the query text only. You still need to have appropriate access to query the data. One advantage of saving only the query text is that you can share a query that is incomplete, even if it isn't a valid query, and use it as a template that other users can complete or customize.
> - The only query option retained by a saved query is the "SQL Version", which governs whether the query uses legacy SQL or standard SQL.